# How can I find what is the table layout that will contain an certain number of cells whose ratio of dimensions is closest to a given aspect ratio

Tags: layout, aspect-ratio, closest

How can I find what is the table layout that will contain an certain number of cells (*N*) whose ratio of dimensions (*x, y*) is closest to a given aspect ratio (*r*)?

I have a number of items that I need to put in a table layout and need to know what my table layout has to be to at least include all of the items while been as close as possible to a given aspect ratio.

**For example** suppose we have *N*=5 items to put in a table layout and our target aspect ratio *r* is 4:3 (1.33), then a 3x2 would be better then a 2x3 table.

3*2 (ratio 3:2 = 1.5 so closer to 1.33)

```
[1][2][3]
[4][5][_]
```

2*3 (ratio 2:3 = 0.67)

```
[1][2]
[3][4]
[5][_]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution in Python.

```
def closest_layout_to_ratio(n, ratio=(4, 3)):
    if n == 1: return (1, 1)

    th_r = max(ratio)/min(ratio)
    th_x = th_r*math.sqrt(n/th_r)
    th_y = n / th_x

    best = (None, None, math.inf)
    for rounder in (math.floor, math.ceil):
        y = max(1, rounder(th_y))
        x = math.ceil(n/y)
        r = x / y
        if abs(r - th_r) < abs(best[2] - th_r):
            best = (int(x), int(y), r)

    return best[:2] if ratio[0] == max(ratio) else best[:2][::-1]
```